# Using HtmlService to create email from spreadsheet, but email is empty

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to generate an email from a Google spreadsheet using the following code:

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var UI = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen() {
  UI.createMenu('Notifications').addItem('New notification', 'createNotification')
.addToUi();  
}

function createNotification() {
  var me = Session.getActiveUser();
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email').evaluate();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: me,
      subject: 'Test email',
      htmlbody: output.getContent()});
}

function getDate () {
  return SS.getRange(SS.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
}

function getEscape () {
  return SS.getRange(SS.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();
}
```

With the following html file for a template:

```
<div>
<h1>Escape Notification:</h1>

<p>Date: <?= getDate();?></p>

<p>Escape:</p>

<p> <?= getEscape();?></p>

</div>
```

The code runs, and I get the test email. However, when I open the email there is no content.

I have tried this a couple of different ways. I've tried serving it as `HtmlOutput` with the `.createHtmlOutputFromFile()` function as well as the method outlined above.

I fear that I am missing something very basic. I have spent several hours pouring over the Apps Script API as well as their examples and tutorials. Nothing that I've found here exactly matches my problem, either. One thing that I noticed is that all of the examples are for `doPost()` or `doGet()` calls. Can this only be done with a user interface or web app?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
htmlbody: output.getContent()
```

to:

```
htmlBody: output.getContent()
```

Use a capital "B"

Comment: This doesn't work. This prints the html into the email instead of formatting it. I did finally figure this out this morning. `htmlbody` should have been `htmlBody`. I knew it was something stupid I was overlooking. However, thanks for getting me to look harder at this section of my code.

Comment: I'll update the answer.  Thank you for letting me know what worked.